# Rails 6 vs Ruby on Rails 7 in where.missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am using the `Milia`/`Philia` gem for doing tenanting. This has worked wonderfully up until our switch to Rails 7.

Between Rails 6 and Rails 7 there is a subtle difference in the SQL generated for the following code.

```
Tenant.set_current_tenant tenant
store = Store.first
from_date = 1.month.ago
to_date = Time.current

store.orders.delivered.where(estimated_arrival_date: from_date..to_date).where.missing(:order_review_requests).where(sales_channel: sales_channels)
```

In Rails 6 the SQL for that last line would be this:

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM `orders` LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_review_requests` ON `order_review_requests`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` AND (order_review_requests.tenant_id = 244) WHERE (orders.tenant_id = 244) AND `orders`.`store_id` = 1269 AND `orders`.`status` = 'delivered' AND `orders`.`shipment_status` = 'delivered' AND `orders`.`estimated_arrival_date` BETWEEN '2023-05-27 06:59:59' AND '2023-06-20 07:00:00' AND `order_review_requests`.`id` IS NULL AND `orders`.`sales_channel` IN (xxxourmarketplaces) LIMIT 1;
```

This works.

In Rails 7 the SQL is like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM `orders` LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_review_requests` `order_review_request` ON `order_review_request`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` AND (order_review_requests.tenant_id = '244') WHERE (orders.tenant_id = '244') AND `orders`.`amazon_store_id` = 1269 AND `orders`.`status` = 'delivered' AND `orders`.`shipment_status` = 'delivered' AND `orders`.`estimated_arrival_date` BETWEEN '2023-05-26 23:59:59' AND '2023-06-20 00:00:00' AND `order_review_request`.`id` IS NULL AND `orders`.`sales_channel` IN (xxxourmarketplaces) LIMIT 1;
```

There is a subtle difference:

in Rails 7: `LEFT OUTER JOIN order_review_requests order_review_request ON`

in Rails 6: `LEFT OUTER JOIN order_review_requests ON`

I suspect this is coming from the fact that `order_review_request` is a `has_one`.

Here's heavily redacted class definitions:

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant

  has_one :review_requestor, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant

  belongs_to :_store, counter_cache: true
  has_one :order_review_request, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And in the gem `Philia` the `acts_as_tenant` looks like this:

```
module Philia
  module Base
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end
    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_tenant
        belongs_to :tenant
        
        validates_presence_of :tenant_id

        default_scope -> { where("#{table_name}.tenant_id = ?", Thread.current[:tenant_id]) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How to get this to behave in the same fashion under Rails 7 as it did under Rails 6?

EDIT:

Here is the actual console output including the select and the mysql error (and sql)

```
irb(main):057:0> store.orders.delivered.where(estimated_arrival_date: to_date..from_date).where.missing(:order_review_request).where(sales_channel: sales_channels).first

  Order Load (5.8ms)  SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders` LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_review_requests` `order_review_request` ON `order_review_request`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` AND (order_review_requests.tenant_id = '16167') WHERE (orders.tenant_id = '16167') AND `orders`.`store_id` = 8356 AND `orders`.`status` = 'delivered' AND `orders`.`shipment_status` = 'delivered' AND `orders`.`estimated_arrival_date` BETWEEN '2023-06-14 05:30:15' AND '2023-06-28 05:30:11' AND `order_review_request`.`id` IS NULL AND `orders`.`sales_channel` = 'testing' ORDER BY `orders`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:151:in `_query': Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'order_review_requests.tenant_id' in 'on clause' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:151:in `_query': Unknown column 'order_review_requests.tenant_id' in 'on clause' (Mysql2::Error)
```

Comment: Is this causing a behaviour problem, or test failure? Note that the singular `order_review_request` is referenced later in the query.

Comment: How do you know this is a problem with the gem?

Comment: The query that's altered is the query related to `.missing`, in the code you provided, an Order has_one :order_review_request, but your query looks for `.missing(:order_review_requests)`, have you tried changing this to `.missing(:order_review_request)`?

Comment: @trueinViso I don't actually know it is a problem with the gem, but as it is the gem that's adding the `tenant_id` scope, that is my guess.

Comment: @LesNightingill Actually problem. Database throws invalid sql exception.

Comment: Try using `where.missing(:order_review_request)` (singular form of symbol). It works for me. At least, it doesn't throw the SQL error! I don't think the tenant feature is relevant to the issue you're seeing. The Rails 7 SQL will not be identical to Rails 6 but I don't believe it should be a problem.

Comment: rails docs (https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing) shows singular form for has_one association

Comment: Actually, I get the same error when doing `where.missing(:order_review_request)`! Interesting that you don't @LesNightingill

Comment: what exactly is the wording of the SQL error? (Best to edit your question and add it there)

Comment: I surmise that OrderReviewRequest includes `acts_as_tenant`, right? Problem is that the default scope in that case uses the table name (order_review_requests) rather than the singular (b/c it's has_one relationship).  I think ActiveRecord has fixed this but Philia has not. You might try overwriting the default scope in OrderReviewRequest that Philia introduces incorrectly, so that the singular form is used. `default_scope -> { where("order_review_request.tenant_id = ?", Thread.current[:tenant_id]) }`. It's a bit of a hack and I haven't tried it. You can also copy the AR .missing code.